# Cite a paper using github markdown syntax

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I am coding a readme for a repo in github, and I want to add a reference to a paper. What is the most adequate way to code in the citation? e.g. As a blockquote, as code, as simple text, etc?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I agree with Horizon_Net that it depends on personal preference.
I like to have something which looks similar to LaTeX.
An example is provided below.
Note that it demonstrates a numeric citation style.
Alphabetic or reading style are possible too.
For numeric citation style, higher numbers should appear later in the text, and this can make satisfying numeric citation style cumbersome.
To avoid this problem, I typically use an alphabetic citation style.

```
"...the **go to** statement should be abolished..." [[1]](#1).

## References
<a id="1">[1]</a> 
Dijkstra, E. W. (1968). 
Go to statement considered harmful. 
Communications of the ACM, 11(3), 147-148.
```

> "...the **go to** statement should be abolished..." [1].
>
> **References**
>
> [1]
> Dijkstra, E. W. (1968).
> Go to statement considered harmful.
> Communications of the ACM, 11(3), 147-148.

On GitHub flavored Markdown and most other Markdown flavors, you can actually click on [1] to jump to the reference.
Apologies for taking Dijkstra his sentence out of context.
The full sentence would make this example more difficult to read.

**EDIT**:
If the references all have a stable link, it is also possible to use those:

```
The field of natural language processing (NLP) has become mostly dominated by deep learning approaches
(Young et al., [2018](https://doi.org/10.1109/MCI.2018.2840738)).
Some are based on transformer neural networks
(e.g., Devlin et al, [2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805)).
```

> The field of natural language processing (NLP) has become mostly dominated by deep learning approaches
> (Young et al., [2018](https://doi.org/10.1109/MCI.2018.2840738)).
> Some are based on transformer neural networks
> (e.g., Devlin et al, [2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805)).

Comment: Can you explain how `[[1]](#1)` work? I didn't find this usage in the markdown syntax. Thank you.

Comment: It is just a link in the usual syntax, that is, `[link text](link)`. However, the link text is `[1]`, which might look confusing.

Comment: Great thanks. Is there any way to make the references list more like a numbered list?  (i.e. first line indent and indented text wrapping).

Comment: Do you mean something like this:
```
1. <a id="1"></a> 
Dijkstra, E. W. (1968).
Go to statement considered harmful.
Communications of the ACM, 11(3), 147-148.
```
or this:
```
1. <a id="1"></a> 
Dijkstra, E. W. (1968). <br>
Go to statement considered harmful.<br> 
Communications of the ACM, 11(3), 147-148.
```

Answer (score 7):

From what I know, there is no built-in mechanism for this. This leads to more subjective opinions, depending on  personal preference. I personally like to have a separate section called **references**. An example would look like the following

## References

- some reference
- another reference

**Update**

Another way would be to use simple HTML embedded in your Markdown.

Comment: Seems fair enough. Thanks for your feedback : )

Answer (score 5):

I just came across a citation in a github comment. They're calling them ["footnotes" as of 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-30-footnotes-now-supported-in-markdown-fields/).

The syntax is link to the footnote in your text using `[^1]`, and then include the expanded reference on a separate line beginning with that same link.

```
Here is a simple footnote[^1]. With some additional text after it.

[^1]: My reference, with further explanation and a [supporting link](https://website.com).

Here is another footnote[^2].

[^2]: Another reference.
```

[image: example of rendered markdown with footnotes at bottom]

Important that you can include the reference source anywhere within the text (conveniently closer to where the reference is actually mentioned), and it will still be rendered at the bottom with all footnotes.

Answer (score 4):

The alternative (to pure markdown) is to use the [new GitHub integration from Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/2021-08-19-enhanced-support-citations-github/):

> ### Enhanced support for citations on GitHub
>
> GitHub now has [built-in support](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/about-citation-files) for [`CITATION.cff`](https://citation-file-format.github.io/) files.
>
> This new feature enables academics and researchers to let people know how to correctly cite their work, especially in academic publications/materials.
>
> Originally proposed by the [research software engineering community](https://www.software.ac.uk/blog/2017-12-12-standard-format-citation-files), [`CITATION.cff`](https://citation-file-format.github.io/) files are plain text files with human- and machine-readable citation information.
> When we detect a CITATION.cff file in a repository, we use this information to create convenient [APA](https://apastyle.apa.org/) or [BibTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) style citation links that can be referenced by others.
>
> ### How this works
>
> Under the hood, we’re using the [ruby-cff](https://github.com/citation-file-format/ruby-cff) RubyGem to parse the contents of the [CITATION.cff](https://github.com/citation-file-format/ruby-cff) file and build a citation string that is then shown in GitHub when someone browses a repository with one of those files1.
>
> [image: citation]

Now, that is helping others making your Github paper easily citable.

But, [as documented](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-citation-files#citing-something-other-than-software), to "add a reference to a paper":

> ### Citing something other than software
>
> If you would prefer the GitHub citation information to link to another resource such as a research article, then you can use the preferred-citation override in CFF with the following types.
>
> | Resource | Type |
> | --- | --- |
> | Research article | article |
> | Conference paper | conference-paper |
> | Book | book |

Extract

```
preferred-citation:
  type: article
  authors:
  - family-names: "Lisa"
    given-names: "Mona"
    orcid: "https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000"
```

Comment: The question is about how to "add a reference to a paper" and not "make my paper easily citable".

Comment: @RikH Agreed. I have edited the answer to include the syntax allowing to reference another resource, such as a research article.